# One can learn faster if he listens to his own voice speaking in target language?

Tags: second-lang-acquisition

I've heard the following statement about foreign language acquisition for a few times:

One can learn a foreign language faster if he can listen to his voice uttering the foreign language.

For example, we may train a voice conversion model to convert some audiobooks recorded in the foreign language to our own voice. And then practicing the foreign language listening to the converted audio clips.

I seems to make sense but I never find any reference supporting that.

Comment: For questions on language learning [languagelearning.se] is an alternative venue.

Comment: I very much doubt the "own voice" was meant as envisioned in this question; I am pretty sure that it means something like "your own vocalisations". Murmuring while learning has been shown to be useful in many human learning tasks, not only for languages.

Comment: This reminds me of how I read once that ancient Romans (and presumably other civilizations, what with Greeks not having any word separator for instance) usually read books out loud, or at least mumbled, not "in their head". Maybe they had a point.

Comment: I agree with @SirCornflakes. The suggestion must be to speak in the new language, record your speech, and then listen to the recordings of yourself and compare your pronunciation to that of native speakers.

Comment: Don't trouble yourself with all that. Just put on Closed Captions under streaming programs or movies etc., then repeat what you hear. //Comparing your speech to what you heard in a recording only works if you can already do the accent. Many people cannot hear themselves. Find yourself a native speaker coach.

Comment: I can readily imagine that a synthesized version of your own voice, speaking the target language with a good accent, can help you improve your accent.

Answer (score 3):

Listening to your own recordings, especially compared to recordings of native speakers, can help you to notice the differences.

Using AI to read an audio book in your voice will probably not do much.

The concept isn't about listening to your voice, but to listen to your pronunciation.